# How to assign a user account db_owner or full permissions to a service application database from share point powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, secure-store

How to assign a user account db_owner or full permissions to a service application database.
For Example:
i restored a secure store service application database from production to staging but application pool account is different in staging and it has no permission on restored database , i don't want to give permissions directly using sql server is any way from sharepoint?